# th element doesn't take tr align attribute

Tags: html, html-table

I have some simple html table and in IE9 the TH elements don't take the left align property of the TR containing them.

```
<TR ALIGN="left">
  <TH>Sample 1</TH>
  <TH>Sample 2</TH>
  <TH>Sample 3</TH>
</TR>
```

All of the headers show up as left aligned in FF, Chrome, Opera but IE 8/9 they are still centered.  Is IE once again not conforming to standards or is it up to browser to decide how to render this?  The way I read it on w3c.org is that it should work like FF and others.

"The order of precedence (from highest to lowest) for the attributes align, char, and charoff is the following:"

- An alignment attribute set on an element within a cell's data (e.g., P).
- An alignment attribute set on a cell (TH and TD).
- An alignment attribute set on a column grouping element (COL and COLGROUP). When a cell is part of a multi-column span, the alignment property is inherited from the cell definition at the beginning of the span.
- **An alignment attribute set on a row or row grouping element (TR, THEAD, TFOOT, and TBODY). When a cell is part of a multi-row span, the alignment property is inherited from the cell definition at the beginning of the span.**
- An alignment attribute set on the table (TABLE).
- The default alignment value.

Comment: Bearing in mind that the `align` attribute is deprecated, IE might actually be the most standards-compliant browser, in this case, by ignoring it. Use `style="text-align: left;` or a stylesheet to style your content.

Comment: Use CSS: `text-align: left`. The `align` attribute was deprecated ages ago.

Comment: I see on the following w3c page that align is deprecated for table and caption elements but doesn't say anything about it for tr element.  http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html#adef-align-TD.  When I go to the TR element section and see "attributes defined elsewhere" then click on the link for align it says nothing about it being deprecated.  So my question is how do I know if it is when w3c doesn't say specifically?  Or is it common knowledge that ALL align attributes are deprecated in html?

Comment: If the W3C isn't explicit enough, it's worth turning to MDN: [`<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/tr).

Comment: Yea I just searched the align attribute which says it's deprecated, but it seems like there are some pages which act like it's still in use for some elements.  Anyhow, thanks for all the comments.  I should have known this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in an old version of IE.

It's also an obsolete feature. Use CSS instead.

```
th { 
    text-align: left;
}
```